# Using Matrix class from System.Drawing.Drawing2D to flatten SVG transformation

Tags: c#, .net, math, matrix, svg

I have SVG document that has RECT tag with MATRIX/SCALE/TRANSLATE transformations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <svg
       xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       version="1.0"
       width="300"
       height="150"
       id="svg2">
      <rect
         width="70"
         height="30"
         x="169.46515"
         y="46.238182"
         id="rect1"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1" />
      <rect
         width="8"
         height="2"
         x="134.69983"
         y="97.45443"
         id="rect2"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1" />
      <rect
         width="2"
         height="2"
         x="-99.804573"
         y="125.0692"
         transform="matrix(-2.6042412e-3,-0.9999966,0.9999966,-2.6042412e-3,0,0)"
         id="rect3"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:1;stroke-opacity:1" />
      <rect
         width="8"
         height="2"
         x="-100.87854"
         y="129.95743"
         transform="matrix(-6.2857322e-4,-0.9999998,0.9999418,-1.0789073e-2,0,0)"
         id="rect4"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:1;stroke-opacity:1" />
      <rect
         width="2"
         height="8"
         x="-99.81971"
         y="134.43823"
         transform="matrix(-2.6042412e-3,-0.9999966,0.9999966,-2.6042412e-3,0,0)"
         id="rect5"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:1;stroke-opacity:1" />
      <path
         d="M 82.592797,67.016361 C 82.597697,77.923711 76.726297,86.769781 69.481867,86.769781 C 62.237427,86.769781 56.366027,77.923711 56.370927,67.016361 C 56.366027,56.109011 62.237427,47.262941 69.481867,47.262941 C 76.726297,47.262941 82.597697,56.109011 82.592797,67.016361 z"
         id="path22095"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#0000ff;stroke-opacity:1" />
      <rect
         width="30"
         height="70"
         x="46.304344"
         y="-239.40808"
         transform="matrix(0,1,-1,0,0,0)"
         id="rect6"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-opacity:1" />
      <rect
         width="2"
         height="2"
         x="121.03672"
         y="97.452477"
         id="rect7"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1" />
    </svg>
```

I would like is to flatten/transform coordinates and get rid of TRANSFORM attribute altogether.

It seems that System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix class has all the required methods, but for some reason result does not look correct. Following is the code I am using:

```
PointF[] coordinates = 
            {
                new PointF(float.Parse(element.Attribute("x").Value), float.Parse(element.Attribute("y").Value))
            };    

var matrix = new Matrix(transform[0], transform[1], transform[2], transform[3], transform[4], transform[5]);
matrix.TransformPoints(coordinates);

element.Attribute("x").Value = coordinates[0].X.ToString();
element.Attribute("y").Value = coordinates[0].Y.ToString();
```

At least in case of RECT it seems to calculate position properly, but because Width/Height remain the same it look different. When I tried to apply TransformPoints to Width/Height as well it didn't help either.

So my question is if it is possible to somehow find original coordinates?

### Update

As @Cimbali suggested I've tried following code but still results don't look correct:

```
var matrix = new Matrix(transform[0], transform[1], transform[2], transform[3], transform[4], transform[5]);
matrix.TransformPoints(coordinates);

var a = Math.Sign(transform[0]) * Math.Sqrt(transform[0] * transform[0] + transform[2] * transform[2]);
var b = Math.Sign(transform[3]) * Math.Sqrt(transform[1] * transform[1] + transform[3] * transform[3]);
var angle = Math.Atan2(transform[1], transform[3]) * 180 / Math.PI;
var newWidth = double.Parse(element.Attribute("width").Value) * a;
var newHeight = double.Parse(element.Attribute("height").Value) * b;

element.Attribute("x").Value = Math.Round(coordinates[0].X, coordinatesPrecision, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();
element.Attribute("y").Value = Math.Round(coordinates[0].Y, coordinatesPrecision, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();
element.Attribute("width").Value = newWidth.ToString();
element.Attribute("height").Value = newHeight.ToString();

if (angle != 0)
    element.Attribute("transform").Value = string.Format("rotate({0})", angle);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from rotations or skews, or these kind of operations.

When moving or scaling a rectangle, it is still a rectangle, so you may modify its coordinates to include these effects and remove them from transform by modifying just the attributes of `<rect />` in your svg. However the other transformations make it not really be a rectangle anymore, or at least not one that has its sides parallel to the `x` and `y` axes.

There are two main ways to go about this :

- keeping a `transform="rotate(angle)"` in your svg, and eventually `skew`s as well, if you use them. 
  For this, you will have to decompose the matrix in different (multiplicative) elements, which is going to be non-trivial, and removing scaling and translating.
- using a `<polygon />` instead of a `<rect />`. This is the simpler option.

### Latter option : polygon

We need the 4 angles of the rectangle : `{(x,y), (x+width,y), (x+width,y+height), (x, y+height)}`

Now you can apply the transform matrix to all of these points, like you did only for the `(x,y)` one, and use them (keeping the order) to draw a polygon.

### Former option : keep rotating

In this version, we keep the `rect`, and try to simplify its `transform` attribute from a matrix to a simple rotation. I will suppose you only rotate, translate, and scale your matrix, and **no skewing** (I've been trying for a while but nothing conclusive).

Then the transform matrix A is written as its 2 first rows (since the 3rd is always `0 0 1`) in column-major order. Thus, since it consists of scaling (along x by `a` and along y by `b`), and then rotating by some angle, where `c = cos(angle)` and `s = sin(angle)`, it is be written as :

```
    | a*c  -a*s  tx |   | transform[0] transform[2] transform[4] |
A = | b*s   b*c  ty | = | transform[1] transform[3] transform[5] |
    |  0     0    1 |   |      0            0            1       |
```

So [from here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13165/48961) comes a pseudo-code for this transformation :

- Add `transform[4]` to the `x` attribute of the `<rect />`
- Add `transform[5]` to the `y` attribute of the `<rect />`
- `a = sqrt( transform[0] * transform[0] + transform[2] * transform[2] )`
- `b = sqrt( transform[1] * transform[1] + transform[3] * transform[3] )`
- `angle = atan2(transform[1], transform[3]) * 180/PI`
- Multiply the rectangle's width by `a` and its height by `b`
- Finally, set the `transform` attribute of `<rect />` to `"rotate(angle)"` (if `angle` is non-zero), and remove it if `angle` is zero.

Taking & correcting the code from your update (because I don't do C# myself alas), we get :

```
element.Attribute("x").Value = Math.Round(coordinates[0].X + transform[4], coordinatesPrecision, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();
element.Attribute("y").Value = Math.Round(coordinates[0].Y + transform[5], coordinatesPrecision, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();

var a = Math.Sqrt(transform[0] * transform[0] + transform[2] * transform[2]);
var b = Math.Sqrt(transform[1] * transform[1] + transform[3] * transform[3]);
var angle = - Math.Atan2(transform[1], transform[3]) * 180 / Math.PI;
var newWidth = double.Parse(element.Attribute("width").Value) * a;
var newHeight = double.Parse(element.Attribute("height").Value) * b;

element.Attribute("width").Value = newWidth.ToString();
element.Attribute("height").Value = newHeight.ToString();

if (angle != 0)
    element.Attribute("transform").Value = string.Format("rotate({0})", angle);
else
    element.RemoveAttribute("transform");
```

An alternative, to have the rotation around the center of the `<rect />` instead of `(0,0)` is by applying the transformation to the coordinates first, thus the following :

```
PointF[] coordinates = { new PointF(
    float.Parse(element.Attribute("x").Value),
    float.Parse(element.Attribute("y").Value)
)};

var matrix = new Matrix(transform[0], transform[1], transform[2], transform[3], transform[4], transform[5]);
matrix.TransformPoints(coordinates);

element.Attribute("x").Value = coordinates[0].X.ToString();
element.Attribute("y").Value = coordinates[0].Y.ToString();

var a = Math.Sqrt(transform[0] * transform[0] + transform[2] * transform[2]);
var b = Math.Sqrt(transform[1] * transform[1] + transform[3] * transform[3]);
var angle = - Math.Atan2(transform[1], transform[3]) * 180 / Math.PI;
var newWidth = double.Parse(element.Attribute("width").Value) * a;
var newHeight = double.Parse(element.Attribute("height").Value) * b;

element.Attribute("width").Value = newWidth.ToString();
element.Attribute("height").Value = newHeight.ToString();

if (angle != 0)
    element.Attribute("transform").Value = string.Format("rotate({0}, {1}, {2})", angle, coordinates[0].X + newWidth/2, coordinates[0].Y + newHeight/2);
else
    element.RemoveAttribute("transform");
```

Comment: Cimbali thanks, you have a good point. Didn't pay attention that `MATRIX` can actually define a rotation as well.  
  So if I want to keep it as a `RECT` is there some straight forward translation from `MATRIX` into `New Coordinates` + `ROTATE`?
  
  And what about `TRANSLATE` and `SCALE` transformations, can these be applied and removed?

Comment: coordinates you provided in your last comment indeed places `rect` into proper position. But is there a way to make it even more readable by providing center for rotate so it is like following: `<rect width="2" height="2" transform="rotate(90,126.32835,98.477325)" x="125.32835" y="97.477325" />`.

Comment: Just tried and it didn't work. From what I understand SVG `rotate` uses (0,0) point for rotation in case `x` and `y` are not provided. And if I use `x+newWidth/2,y+newHeight/2` then position won't be correct because `x` has a negative number. Does this make sense?

Comment: Cimbali, I just marked you answer, because it does answer my main question. I've removed few comments to simplify things, but still would like to get coordinates to make readable as suggested in my comment. Is that possible?

Comment: Aha, because as I mentioned `newX` is `-99.804573` and rotation happens around `0,0`. So if we do what you suggested it will still be negative and be placed in wrong place. You can actually place that `rect` into SVG file and open in IE to see the results.

Comment: Cimbali, second version didn't work unfortunately, `rect` shifted.

Comment: @Hayk what coordinates do you get ?

Comment: Cimbali, for example this `<rect width="8" height="2" x="-100.87854" y="129.95743" transform="matrix(-6.2857322e-4,-0.9999998,0.9999418,-1.0789073e-2,0,0)" />` becomes following `<rect width="7.99953626242286" height="2.00011598727547" rx="1.243" ry="0.3" x="130.0128" y="99.47685" transform="rotate(90.6181444783282, 134.012600772813, 100.47691041063)" />`. Visually it is shifted and rotated from original position.